# Join 2 large size tables (50 Gb and 1 billion records)

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-2.0, apache-spark-sql-repartition, parquet-dataset

I have 2 super large tables which I am loading as dataframe in parquet format with one join key. Now the issues I need help in :

1. I need to tune it, as I am getting OOM errors due to Java heap space.
2. I have to apply left join.

There will not be any null values, so it might not improve performance.

3. What should I do to achieve this scenario?

Jfyi: While loading this parquet data I have already applied repartition based on a column.

1. I have loaded both df1 and df2
2. When I tried caching it, it failed, but since it needs to be used multiple times,caching is required , persisting is not an option.
3. Applied repartitioning on both df to evenly distribute the data

Comment: Can you add more details like the size of the cluster used, what instances are used, spark configurations used? Its easier to come up with a solution that way. Cheers

Comment: 10 node 100 gb 3 num-executors.

Comment: Also this tuning was more from the application level tuning by techniques like repartitioning, salting etc.

Comment: Could you share the instance type as well. Also what was the idea behind choosing 3 executors?

Comment: That is the predefined cluster configuration. My question is more from what best we can do at application level

Comment: I think the best you can do is do is spark executor tuning. Check out this link https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/best-practices-for-successfully-managing-memory-for-apache-spark-applications-on-amazon-emr/